# transform array using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array looking like this:

```
[Object { id=50, name="My Town"}, Object { id=61, name="My second town"}]
```

which I need to transform to:

```
Object { 61=true, 50=true}
```

How do I do that using underscore.js (or regular js)?

thanks
Thomas

Comment: What does that `true` represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use just `forEach` method of native array , in underscore its `_.each`

```
 var arr = [{ id:50, name:"My Town"},{ id:61, name:"My second town"}];
 var obj = {};
 arr.forEach(function(val){   obj[val.id] = true; });
 console.log(obj)//Object { 61=true, 50=true}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var res = {};
var objs = [ { id: 50 }, { id: 61} ];
objs.forEach(function (d) { res[d.id] = true; });
```